# good backadmin gem for a cms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backend

What Im looking is a good background gem for a cms made in Ruby on Rails.
The workflow I had in mind is this.

All articles are divided into categories. So when the user has no made any categories the user cannot enter any articles. 
So I need a section for making, updating, deleting categories.
Then I need a way a user chooses a category and then the user can enter a article which will be a part of that category.

Does anyone know a gem which can provide this. 
I have tried activeadmin but it looks it cannot do the job,

Roelof

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces would be a great place to start looking.

ps. ActiveAdmin probably can do the job, but without seeing the code you've got, we can't help you fix it.

Comment: The code I have so far can be found here : https://github.com/roelof1967/tamara_site/tree/admin_section

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a blogging app

This one http://fdv.github.com/typo/ seems good. They have a demo, so you can test run it.

[refinery](http://refinerycms.com/) Is more like a cms, but there is a demo, so it take 10 secounds to see if it is what you want